# How to use vuex namespaced getters with arguments?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, getter, vuex

I have issue when Im using vuex.

I have getters in namespaced module and I cant figurę out how to get the data with Ii when Im passing some arguments.

```
this.$store.getters.feeders.getFeedersById(id)
```

And in maper.

```
...mapGetters({
   feeders: ['feeders/getFeedersById'](this.id)
```

Getting error like this getter is not a function. What else shoudl I do?

Comment: Have you seen this question on the official GitHub page maybe: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/688

Comment: Still not working for the edited function

Comment: Works now :D Thanks! :P

Comment: So, is the final edit the one working with namespaces? Maybe someone would come along with the same issue and can be able to see where s/he should fix ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
feedersById(state) {
    return rowId => {
        if (state.feedersArray.hasOwnProperty(rowId)) {
            return state.feedersArray[rowId].map(id => state.feeders[id]);
        }

    }
},

feedersId() {
  if (this.rowData) {
   return this.$store.getters['feeders/feedersById'](this.rowData.ac_id);
  }
}
```

Okey I had some mistake there and now it works properly. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also declare a getter function like this:

```
feedersById: (state) => rowID => {
  if (state.feedersArray.hasOwnProperty(rowId)) {
    return state.feedersArray[rowId].map(id => state.feeders[id]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easier way is to use name spaced getters:

```js
computed(){
    ...mapGetters('feeders', ['getFeedersById'])
}
```